# Is there a way to speed up the in-memory full text search indexing speed?

Tags: h2

To my surprise I have discovered that the indexing of documents into the full text search engine in H2 is comparably slow and I would like to speed that up.

I'm using the in-memory version of H2, which makes this case especially surprising.

Some benchmarks using 100k small documents (only title and some tags):

- Using `org.h2.fulltext.FullTextLucene.init` it takes ~15s to index.
- Using `org.h2.fulltext.FullText.init` makes no change.
- The SQL inserting alone (i.e. full text indexing disabled) only takes 1s.
- When using Elasticsearch (with bulk indexing) I would expect that this amount would be processed and be searchable within 3s, i.e. it's even stored on disk.

Some additional info which might help:

- Connection is reused.
- No stop words are used (but that wouldn't make much difference in terms of documents size).
  EDIT_2: I added a big list of stop words (>100). This made it like <10% faster (~15s to ~14s).
- The SQL inserting alone (i.e. full text indexing disabled) only takes 1s, so the problem should be with the full text search indexing.
- The official [tutorial](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html) and page about [performance](http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html) don't seem to offer a solution.
- There doesn't seem to be a possibility for bulk indexing like in Elasticsearch.
- EDIT_1: I also tried to create the SQL table and inserts FIRST (which take 1s) and AFTER THAT create the full text search index and run `FullTextLucene.reindex()`. But that makes the process even a bit slower.

If it's of any help, here's the code how the index is created and the inserts are made:

Create index:

```
private void createTablesAndLuceneIndex() {
    try {
        final Statement statement = this.createStatement();
        statement.execute("CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS FT_INIT FOR \"org.h2.fulltext.FullTextLucene.init\"");
        statement.execute("CALL FT_INIT()");
        //  FullTextLucene.setIgnoreList(this.conn, "to,this"); // Do we need stop words?
        FullTextLucene.setWhitespaceChars(this.conn, " ,.-");

        // Set up SQL table & Lucene index
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE " + PNS_VIDEOS + "(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, TITLE VARCHAR, TAGS VARCHAR, ACTORS VARCHAR)");
        statement.execute("CALL FT_CREATE_INDEX('PUBLIC', '" + PNS_VIDEOS + "', NULL)");

        // Close statement
        statement.close();
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        throw new SqlTableCreationException(e); // todo logging?!
    }
}
```

Index document:

```
public void index(final PnsVideo pnsVideo) {
    try (PreparedStatement statement = this.conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO " + PNS_VIDEOS + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

        statement.setInt(1, this.autoKey.getAndIncrement());
        statement.setString(2, pnsVideo.getTitle());
        statement.setString(3, Joiner.on(",").join(pnsVideo.getTags()));
        statement.setString(4, Joiner.on(",").join(pnsVideo.getActors()));
        statement.execute();

    } catch (final SQLException e) {
        throw new FTSearchIndexException(e); // todo logging?!
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: To whom it may concern: So I just used the in-memory Lucene implementation directly with unoptimized code from an example with deprecated stuff (see [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/lucene/lucene-ramdirectory-example/)) and it sped up the indexing by 90%, compared to my H2 tryout (100k docs = ~1,6s). And as it looks it works fine. Either I made a huge mistake in H2 or their full text search implementation is just bad. Can't be sure.